# how to display dashboard in visualforce page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

how to display dashboard using visual force page in sales force.please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

No, at this point there is no builtin component to show a dashboard in VF page. You essentially have two alternatives:

1. Do your own visualization, I found extJS of great help and I think some people use jQuery Flot plugin for some basic visualisation
2. A hack, every dashboard has a unique URL, something like `https://naX.salesforce.com/01Z700000xxxxx`, just create a visual container like iframe or such and reference the content from that URL

Comment: i displayed dashboard images in iframe in apex page . but i want display visualforce page not in iframe please let me know mmix.

Comment: Well you can always try to put dashboard url in DIV's src attribute and load dashboard inside a div but I would be carefull about that. Not sure it would work properly due to cross-domain scripting (VF pages and factory pages come from different domains)